# How do I add 1 into a column of numbers and replace null value with 1 as well in python

Tags: python, addition

```py
out_df['# of Days'] = out_df['# of Days'].replace('',1)
out_df['# of Days'] += 1

print(out_df)
```

Would work except when cell's have NULL as their value, it does not add the 1 value.

Trying to add 1 to the entire column including empty cell in the column.

Answer (score 0):

```
def newValue(value):
    if value == "":
        return 1
    if value is None:
        return 1
    return value + 1

out_df['# of Days'] = newValue(out_df['# of Days'])
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**